# Delayed response in TableView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to make a simple program which involves a tableView. When I click on a cell in the tableView, it should reveal more information about the cell that was clicked on `DetailedViewController`. However, when I click the cell, it remains highlighted and it does not reveal the information of the cell. So I used `NSLog()` statements to identify where the program was getting stuck. `NSLog()` statement that I introduced in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` method indicates that I get a response for the cell that was click prior to the last one.

Any idea why is this happening? Also, why do I not see the DetailedViewController when I click the cell?

For the sake of brevity, `Numbers.h` contains two variable: `NSString * name` and `int long long number`. DetailedViewController is a simple VC with two labels: `nameField` and `numberField` and they are suppose to get updated when I click the respective cell.

I would sincerely appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "DetailedViewController.h"
#import "Numbers.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize numberList;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    NSLog(@"loaded Nib file");
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"View Numbers";
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"Loaded view controller");
    Numbers *num1 = [[Numbers alloc] init];
    Numbers *num2 = [[Numbers alloc] init];
    num1.name = @"Number 1";
    num1.number = 12345;

    num2.name = @"Number 2";
    num2.number = 23456;

    numberList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]  initWithObjects:num1,num2, nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setNumberList:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return numberList.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"In cellForRowAtIndexPath:");
    static NSString *cellIndetifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIndetifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2    reuseIdentifier:cellIndetifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[numberList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Row selected = %d", indexPath.row);

    Numbers *numberToDisplay = [[Numbers alloc] init];
    numberToDisplay.name = [[numberList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name]; // why can I not use dot notation here?
    numberToDisplay.number = [[numberList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] number]; // why can I not use dot notation here?

    DetailedViewController *detailedViewController = [[DetailedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailedViewController.nameLabel.text = numberToDisplay.name;
    detailedViewController.numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lli", numberToDisplay.number];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailedViewController animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. That should give you information about the cell that's currently being selected.

The cell you're getting from didDeselectRowAtIndexPath is the row that gets deselected, after you selected a new cell. That's why it's behind.

Comment: thanks @Simon Germain. I did not realize that I had misspelled the method name. By the way, any idea why `DetailedViewController` is not loading?

Comment: No idea, the code that's in there is correct, it should work. That `SecondViewController` got pushed onto a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Ok.. I solved that problem. I had to make my `SecondViewController` root view controller of UINavigationController in `AppDelegate.m`. Thanks for your help once again!

Comment: I have posted another question on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762846/discrepancy-in-passing-data-between-classes. Can you please take a look? Thanks!

Comment: Jeeeez, would have taken me FOREVER to spot that (just done it myself)!  Thanks for this!  Have a +1 from me two years late :)  Apple should put a pop up in asking if you're share you meant didDeselect!

Comment: I just did this same thing. Wondering why I only see my select action on the second cell I select... feeling stupid!

Answer (score 2):

You've implemented `didDeselect` instead of `didSelect` - just change the method name and try again.

Comment: thanks @ikuragames. I did not realize that I had misspelled the method name. By the way, any idea why `DetailedViewController` is not loading?

Comment: Check whether self.navigationController is nil when you try to push the new view controller. It shouldn't be nil - if it is then you've not set up your navigation controller correctly.

Comment: Ok.. I solved that problem. I had to make my `SecondViewController` root view controller of UINavigationController in `AppDelegate.m`. Thanks for your help once again!