# Discrepancy in passing data between classes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Part 1 of the code works fine. Part 2 shows minor changes in the code which causes the code to stop working (without errors/warnings) as expected.

Part 1: (Works)

```
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "ClassB.h"

@implementation ClassA

- (void) sendData
{
    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HI!"];
    ClassB *classBObject = [[ClassB alloc] init];
    classBObject.dataToDisplay = temp;
    self.view = classBObject.view;
}

@end
```

Interface of ClassB:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ClassB : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@property NSString * dataToDisplay;

@end
```

Implementation of ClassB:

```
#import "ClassB.h"

@implementation ClassB

@synthesize dataToDisplay, textLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    textLabel.text = dataToDisplay;
}

@end
```

Part 2:

But if I change `- (void)sendData` of ClassA to the following:

```
- (void) sendData
    {
        NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HI!"];
        ClassB *classBObject = [[ClassB alloc] init];
        classBObject.textLabel.text = temp; // statement changed from Part 1.
        self.view = classBObject.view;
    }
```

and remove `textLabel.text = dataToDisplay;` from `implementation` of `ClassB`, the `textLabel` on view controller of `ClassB` does not get updated. Can you please suggest, why is it so?

Thanks!

Edit 1:

In the statement: `classBObject.textLabel.text = temp; // statement changed from Part 1.`, I had missed `.text` while copy pasting. Please excuse me for that.

Comment: Should be ´classBObject.textLabel.text = temp;´.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the second technique is incorrect (besides the missing `.text` at the end of `textLabel`) is that when you return from the class B initializer, the underlying `UILabel` corresponding to `textLabel` undoubtedly has not been created yet. If you look at this [diagram](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW2) you'll see that the view configuration is not completed at the end of the the initialization methods, but rather upon access. So you must defer any access of the user interface controls until `viewDidLoad`.

---

**Update:**

When I run the following code, I get "0x0" in my log, proving that the `UILabel` on my second view is still `nil` and has not been initialized yet, as I would have expected. When the `viewDidLoad` in my second controller sets `self.textLabel.text = self.dataToDisplay` in `viewDidLoad`, it works like a champ (as it does for you). But the `UILabel` `IBOutlet` property is just not reliable until `viewDidLoad`.

```
SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

NSLog(@"%p", controller.textLabel);

controller.dataToDisplay = @"from first view";

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I am still trying to understand the diagram that you referred to. If I understand your response correctly, you are saying that `textLabel` of `ClassB` will not be loaded until the view of ClassB is loaded. Am I right? I inserted: `NSLog(@"classBObject.textLabel.text = %@", classBObject.textLabel.text)` in ClassA implementation and in worked fine. Why is that so?

Comment: Hmm. After init/alloc but before `viewDidLoad` in my ARC project, my `classBObject.textLabel` is `nil`. Are you using ARC? If not, your `textLabel` may not be initialize yet. I don't know. All I know is that you simply cannot update user interface objects until `viewDidLoad` (or if you're doing it manually, in `loadView`). That's the entire purpose of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. But I am not able to understand properly. I am able to get a response to my NSLog statement successfully.

Comment: And you're logging `classBObject.textLabel` immediately after `[[ClassB alloc] init]` and the `textLabel` is not `nil`?!? I don't understand that.

Comment: And you're not manually doing anything with that `UILabel` in your class B implementation's initialization method, are you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17656/discussion-between-rob-and-rut)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a UITextLabel to NSString. Try

```
classBObject.textLabel.text = temp;
```

Comment: i am sorry I had missed .text while pasting, but it still does not work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line...

```
    classBObject.textLabel = temp; // statement changed from Part 1.
```

to

```
    classBObject.textLabel.text = temp; // statement changed from Part 1.
```

Also, you should do

```
    [self.view addSubView:classBObject.view]; //using navigation controller or presenting modal viewcontroller would be recommended.
```

instead of

```
    self.view = classBObject.view;
```

after this line, update the label's text with your value.

```
    classBObject.textLabel.text = temp; // statement changed from Part 1.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had missed `.text` while pasting the question. Sorry about that. However the code still does not work.

Comment: you have to write it after [self.view addSubView:classB.view];

Comment: the problem is.... textLabel would be on classB View. Hence, it would be nil, until you have the classB view added

Comment: I know this is an old answer and that you were just fixing the obvious problems in the OP's code, but as an aside, it's inadvisable for the OP to use `addSubview` to transition to  `ClassB` view controller at all. And if `ClassB` is a true subview (i.e. shown at the same time), then the OP should follow through and implement view controller containment completely (e.g. `addChildViewController`, `didMoveToParentViewController:self`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're using a weak reference to the `UILabel` in your `classB` interface. Any reason you're not using a `strong` reference? The only time you want to use `weak` references is to avoid retain cycles. Most likely, your `UILabel` isn't being retained.

Where do you initialize your `UILabel`?

Comment: I have initialized UILabel in ClassB. I used weak reference because it was the default option. However, I changed the label to `strong`, but it did not make any difference.

Comment: I am trying to understand the concept of retain cycles. Can you please point some book/article that can help me understand this concept in detail?

Comment: A retain cycles is when you have 2 objects that have references to each other. If the both retain each other, it's impossible to deallocate them. In that case, you want to use a weak reference on one of them.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. When you want to reference two classes mutually, you use @class (rather than #import) in one of them. Is it for the same reason as you described above?

Comment: No, that's just an inclusion recursion. A retain cycle has to do with memory management.

Comment: As an aside, `IBOutlet` references should generally be weak. See [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW10).